# creating unknown class with Guice without injector

Tags: guice

We have one and "only" one call to our injector...

```java
Application app = injector.getInstance(Application.class);
app.start();
```

This has worked EXTREMELY well.  Deep in the app though, we would like to have a certain Provider or something that creates a Class and more importantly wires his injections up as well.  It may be something with AssistedInject but I am not 100% sure.  We need something like the following

```java
private Provider<SomeInterface> stuff;

public SomeInterface create(Class runtimeInst) {
  return stuff.get(runtimeInst);
}
```

Is there a way to do that at all?

Comment: Have you already look at [provider bindings](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings)? Should be very possible...

Comment: yes, though I modified my example as I think there was confusion in that there is only ONE thing I want to return from the provider.get when in fact, it is called many times and I want many things returned rather than just the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As condit mentioned, if you look up the "default bindings" available on the [Injector](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html) documentation, you'll see that an Injector can provide:

> - This `Injector` instance itself
> - A `Provider<T>` for each binding of type `T`
> - The java.util.logging.Logger for the class being injected
> - The Stage in which the Injector was created

This means that in any given class, if you've told Guice how to bind a `T` or `Provider<T>`, you can always `@Inject` either a `T` or `Provider<T>` and Guice will handle the wrapping or unwrapping through Provider as necessary.

In your particular case, it looks like you either need to specifically inject one of the following:

- `Provider<SomeInterface>`, which returns whichever implementation you've bound `SomeInterface` to
- `Provider<SomeGuyImplementingSomeInterface>`, which you can use to exactly specify exactly which `SomeInterface` implementor you need
- `@SomeAnnotation Provider<SomeInterface>` (where you've bound `@SomeAnnotation SomeInterface` to the particular implementor `SomeGuyImplementingSomeInterface` in a module somewhere), if you want to be able to configure which non-default implementation to use all the way out at the Module level
- `Injector`, if all else fails, and you absolutely need to get an instance from Guice based on a class literal kept a variable, so you can call `injector.getInstance(clazz)` directly. This will be the exact same Injector you used to create the topmost class, and will work exactly the same without you having to keep that Injector reference yourself. Try to avoid this solution unless you really need it; injecting only exactly what you need will make your testing easier and make your dependencies much more obvious.

Comment: ah, @Inject private Injector injector; works great.  I didn't realize that was bound....pretty sweet.

Comment: @Dean Great! Just use it sparingly. Specific injected classes and Providers help make your code testable and your dependencies clear, but it sounds like your case is what Injector injection was designed for. Good luck!

Comment: definitely...I seem to run into one case per project where we want that and no more.